# Connection error during serverless deploy of python package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy a sample python code into aws using serverless. I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/).

My yml file is as follows

```
service: myservice
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  deploymentBucket: table.detector.code

# you can overwrite defaults here
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

I've also used serverless config credentials and entered my access id and key.
After running serverless deploy I get the following:

```
Unable to find good bind path format
 For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Now I'm using windows 10 for this and I have a docker installed as well. How do I make serverless deploy this into lambda? What did I miss?

Comment: From the context it sounds like you were following the [Windows notes](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#checkered_flag-windows-dockerizepip-notes) from the [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements). Is Docker for sure running when you deploy?

Comment: same issue here and docker is running